# How many times a variable repeats in a table?

Tags: jquery, mysql, variables, repeat

I'm trying to figure out how to create a query to pull up how many times in a row one value repeats before it changes. My goal is to count the number of time the "yes" column repeats before it hits a "no."  I want the largest repetition count of "yes."

For example if I have table like the following

```
+------+-------+-------+
| Id   | Name  | Blue  |
+------+-------+-------+
| 1    | Sam   | yes   |
| 2    | Mike  | yes   |
| 3    | Carol | yes   |
| 4    | Bob   | yes   |
| 5    | John  | yes   |
| 6    | Adam  | no    |
| 7    | David | yes   |
| 8    | Maria | no    |
+------+-------+-------+
```

What I want is a query that pulls up all rows where "blue = yes" repetitively.  Again, trying to count the number of rows in a row where "blue = yes."  So the result should be this.

```
+------+-------+-------+
| Id   | Name  | Blue  |
+------+-------+-------+
| 1    | Sam   | yes   |
| 2    | Mike  | yes   |
| 3    | Carol | yes   |
| 4    | Bob   | yes   |
| 5    | John  | yes   |
+------+-------+-------+
```

I was thinking I could just do it by

```
SELECT * where blue = "yes" and id = id + 1
```

but that doesn't return any data.  I just can't quite figure out the logic to pull up the query correctly.  I did some research and thought maybe a temporary table query would work, but just not sure how to do that. Thank you for any help!

Comment: if Maria had blue=yes, would you want David and Maria to be returned also?

Comment: If Sam had blue=no, would you want no results, or Mike,Carol,Bob,John?

Comment: I want it to return the rows where the yes column repeats, no matter who the name is.  Once it hits no, basically the query should stop.  My goal is to count the largest number of times "yes" repeats.  I edited my question to try to make that clearer.

Comment: I don't disagree with this problem, but this is a perfect case where 30 seconds of server-side coding can solve a huge sql-only problem.

Comment: I could probably do it with PHP sure, I was just wanted to see if there was a way I could pull the query right off instead of having to do it that way.

Comment: you contradict yourself.  either it should stop at the first no, or you want the largest number of times yes repeats.  e.g. if you had yes,yes,no,yes,yes,yes do you want the first set of yes's or the second set?  and you didn't answer my question about if the first record has no

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the query pulls all the information from the sub query.
The `WHERE` clause takes the id of the sub query, makes sure `Blue` of the previous id and current id are "yes". The `OR` is there to make sure single points of reference aren't lost (Without the `OR`, you lose the first value).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af4674/1

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
id INT(12),
Name VARCHAR(30),
Blue VARCHAR(30)
);


INSERT INTO TableA (id, Name, Blue) VALUES
(1, "Sam", "yes"),
(2, "Mike", "yes"),
(3, "Carol", "yes"),
(4, "Bob", "yes"),
(5, "John", "yes"),
(6, "Adam", "no"),
(7, "David", "yes"),
(8, "Maria", "no");

SELECT   id, Name, Blue 
FROM     (
           SELECT   id, Name, Blue
           FROM     TableA 
          ) t
WHERE    ( 
           SELECT   Blue 
           FROM     TableA 
           WHERE    id = (select min(id) FROM TableA WHERE id > t.id)
          ) = "yes" 
          AND
          ( 
           SELECT   Blue 
           FROM     TableA 
           WHERE    id = t.id
          ) = "yes" 
           OR       (
                     SELECT    Blue 
                     FROM      TableA 
                     WHERE    id = (select max(id) FROM TableA WHERE id < t.id)
                    ) = "yes" 
           AND      (
                     SELECT   Blue 
                     FROM     TableA 
                     WHERE    id = t.id
                    ) = "yes"
```

Comment: in general relying on ids to be consecutive isn't a good idea

Comment: Yeah agree on the id's being consecutive.  Would there be a way to just call the biggest run of them?  This way all the "yes" rows are being pulled, and I would to just pull out the longest "streak" of yes's.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but it seems to work:

```
SET @count=(SELECT count(*) FROM test);

SET @get_count=(SELECT count(CASE WHEN
  @count >= id AND NOT blue="yes" THEN @count:=id END)
    FROM test ORDER BY id ASC);

SELECT * FROM test WHERE id < @count ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Set a variable equal to the number of records. Loop through the records by `id` ascending. The first time `NOT blue="yes"` set `@count` to that `id`. The case will always be false thereafter since the remaining ids will always be greater than `@count`. Then just run a query that selects id's less than `@count`.

Comment: I understand the logic there but unfortunately got a syntax error when I tried to run it.

Comment: What is the error? Admittedly I built this using a random online environment thing, but it seems to work [here](https://paiza.io/projects/NgfhqTrOAFYktOle97FTCQ?language=mysql).